# How to fully reset Gnome/Dconf settings?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, dconf

I already deleted everything that I could in based on the answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults, but one things remains: `Devices > Displays > Resolution` is still set to my custom value after deleting everything I could find in my home folder, although everything else in Gnome has reset.

Maybe I missed something. If I log out and back in as another user (for example as `root` instead of my normal user), then the resolution goes back to the default for that user. When I log back into my user, it goes back to the customized resolution.

Comment: Does your user account have a `~/.config/monitors.xml` file?

Comment: Ah, yes, I do. The other question's answer hadn't mentioned that one.